# The garbled text of Keil u vision4

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, keil

i want to write a program to rank the score
there's my attempt:

```
int i,j,s[5][2],tmp,p;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("plz input student numder:\n");
    scanf("%d",&s[i][0]);
    printf("score:\n");
    scanf("%d",&s[i][1]);
}
for(p=0;p<5;p++)  
{                         
        for(i=p+1;i<5;i++)
   {
            if(s[i][1]>s[p][1])
             {
                tmp=s[p][1];
                s[p][1]=s[i][1];
                s[i][1]=tmp;
                j=s[p][0];
                s[p][0]=s[i][0];
                s[i][0]=j;
           } 
     }
      }
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    printf("rank%d %d %d\n",i+1,s[i][0],s[i][1]);
    }
    return 0;
```

but the output is:
plz input student numder:
123202033
score:
65
plz input student numder:
125425152
score:
56
plz input student numder:
102323122
score:
98
plz input student numder:
102325244
score:
75
plz input student numder:
210232322
score:
45
rank1 21426 98
rank2 23548 75
rank3 -5647 65
rank4 -10752 56
rank5 -7166 45
 鼢
        Dt
  ?? ?0??????"屪?@ ? @ ? ? ?                 
        9"x噈惄u  v0??~ "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving very large input in the student id

plz input student numder:
**123202033**

That is not corresponding to valid range an integer

that's why it is giving output in negatives

Comment: so...how to extend the integer?

Comment: @賴言厚: What compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: short int and int: -32,767 to 32,767
unsigned short int and unsigned int: 0 to 65,535
long int: -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned long int: 0 to 4,294,967,295

Comment: `int i,j,s[5][2],tmp,p;`  change to   `long int i,j,s[5][2],tmp,p;?`

Comment: thanks you . i solve the range problem,but the end of output is still appear garbled text   
like this:  
鼢
Dt
?? ?0??????"屪?@ ? @ ? ? ? 
9"x噈惄u v0??~ "?

Comment: initialize your 2d array to zero

Comment: oh!I got it.I deeply appreciated your assistance.